# Ionic Radius of Iodine in High Temperature Form

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

The ionic radius of iodine in the high temperature form can be determined once the unit cell is known, but how can I calculate the radius of $\ce{I}$ given that the cubic lattice parameter is 6.10 Å.

Answer (score 5):

Considering by `cubic lattice` you mean a Simple Cubic structure, you could do the following:

- [Reference image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLTB2.jpg)
- [Reference image2](http://chemistry.umeche.maine.edu/~amar/spring2012/bur25542_1219.jpg)

(could not put it here because of copyright)

In a cubic lattice the atoms touch each other along the edges(see image1 and image2), hence the edge length/parameter will be equal to twice the radius (see image2). 
$$\therefore\ \ce{Edge\ Length(a)=2\times radius(r)}$$
$$\therefore\ a \ = \ 2\times r$$

This method can be adopted for any lattice, you only need to find the axis along which the atoms touch each other(image1 bottom row).

---

If they exhibited an fcc close packing structure, you would notice that the atoms touch each other along a face-diagonal.

$$
\begin{align}
\therefore\ce{Length\ of\ face\ diagonal&\ =\ radius\ of\ top\ left\ atom +\\
                                        &\quad\ diameter\ of\ atom\ at\ face-center + \\
                                        &\quad\ radius\ of\ bottom\ left\ atom}\\
\therefore\ce{Length\ of\ face\ diagonal&\ =\ r\ + ( 2\times r ) + r}\\
\therefore\ce{\sqrt{2}\times a&\ =\ 4\times r}\\
\therefore\ce{a&\ = 2\sqrt{2}\times r}
\end{align}
$$

---

Similarly for bcc structure the atoms touch each other along the body-diagonal 
$$\therefore\ce{\sqrt{3}\times a\ =\ 4\times r}$$

Comment: So, the answer must be in terms of the diagonal unit of the cube.

Comment: @ordinarychemistrystudent I thought you stated it followed a `cubic lattice`, in which case it would be the first section, that is $a\ =\ 2\times r$ where $a$ is edge length